# I cannot access my IIS7 site on the network

Tags: iis-7

I have an IIS7 site that works fine while on the server, however refuses to work from anywhere on the network.

When logged onto the IIS Server itself (with remote desktop) then the website shows fine, as per this link (I used port 801 for this site):

```
http://localhost:801/
```

However when attempting to access this site from the network, it refuses to work, giving the generic 'cannot display the webpage' message, while using the following link:

```
http://<<my IIS server>>:801/
```

Another thing I have noticed however is that on the network the default page (port 80) of the IIS server DOES work.  I.E this following link shows the standard IIS7 page:

```
    http://<<my IIS server>>:80/
```

Most of the help topics I've read point to it being a firewall issue, however as a test I disabled all firewall settings on the IIS Server, yet it still refused to show.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?
Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my post above.  With further testing it is indeed a firewall issue, coupled with the anti-virus software on the machine.  Sine I am a new user I am unable to close my own question.

Comment: But you can answer it and then accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with computer name and / or IP Address

```
e.g: http://192.168.1.105:80/
     http://DELL_PC:80/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following tests:

Check connectivity from both computers. 
Firewall settings, temporary disable the firewall from all profiles (private, domain, public) if this works, try adding a Port Rule to your firewall allowing incoming connections to port 80.
Also, it'd be important to check the bindings configuration of your website, bindings specify the address the server should listen to for incoming connections, make sure you have 'All Unassigned'.

Reference : [Click Here !!](https://superuser.com/questions/289379/cant-access-iis7-from-my-home-network)